# Creating a systemd service for Flask via nginx

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python

I'm running a Flask application on a server via nginx. I want to create a systemd file and here's what I have:

```
[Unit]
Description=my123 website
After=syslog.target
Requires=postgresql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user_123/my_web_app/run.py &
ExecStop=
Restart=on-abort
WorkingDirectory=/home/user_123/my_web_app/
SyslogIdentifier=my_web_app
User=user_123

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Locally I run it as `./run.py`. Now, what should I have in `ExecStart` and `ExecStop`? I think `ExecStart` is correct because I have the `&` in it. But how about `ExecStop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should **never** add `&` to `ExecStart`.  That will make systemd think that your unit is the process doing the forking.  Also, you do not need `ExecStop` for a service that understands SIGTERM (flask's built-in webserver does), systemd knows where to send the signal.

i.e. systemd tracks the PID that `ExecStart` started at and then knows where to send SIGTERM when you ask to terminate the process.

(A unit `type=` can make forks a little more complicated than that.  But the default unit `type=` considers that there are no forks.)

#### Extra

Running the built-in flask server behind Nginx will render you **very** vulnerable to even a **trivial DoS attack**.  The flask built-in server is not meant for production use.  With Nginx you should be using something like [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Flask docs have a [section on uwsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/uwsgi/), and you can map the command line easily to edit uWSGI configuration file options.  And uWSGI docs have a [section on systemd](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html).  And you really should be using systemd to start a real webserver akin of uWSGI, not the flask built-in one.

Comment: `That will make systemd think that your unit is the process doing the forking` -- why is it bad?

Comment: @ako25 - That's actually not pedantically correct since systemd does not give a full shell to `ExecStart=` but is bad 'cause: (1) it is not the way that the designers of systemd envisioned `ExecStart=` (yes, that's a very valid argument, you do not want to reinvent the wheel); and (2) systemd tracks the PID, if you fork then systemd is tracking the wrong PID (this is even more significant if you have other signals to send, SIGHUP is sometimes used with webservers); and (3) that `&` will actually end in `sys.argv` inside `run.py` (and am confident you didn't expect that).

Comment: ok. "No, you should never add & to ExecStart." --> how am I supposed to start my application then?

Comment: if I just run as "./run.py" and disconnect from the ssh, it'll terminate also.

Comment: @ako25 - `systemctl start <whatever name you gave to the unit file>`?  Have a look at how `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service` looks like.  That's one of your requirements.  That's what you "execute" with `systemctl start postgres.service`.

Comment: [This exhibit in the systemd House of Horror](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/two-services.html) should prove instructive.